# Ruby Regexp Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Following usernames should be allowed:

```
Foo-Bar
Foobar
Fooo_123
Foob123_1
Foo-bar-123
```

Following user names should not be allowed:

```
_Foobar_
F-o-o-b-a-r
-Foobar-
_-Foobar-_
```

This means: The string is allowed to be 3 to 20 characters long. There is only one dash or underscore allowed every three characters. Not at the beginning and not and the end. You are only allowed to use at most 2 of a dash or underscore, a maximum of 3 numbers, but a minimum of 3 letters.

This is the Regexp I've done so far, but I already failed at allowing dashes at the front and end:

```
/^[^\-_][a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}[^\-_]$/
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably too complicated for a single regex, and if you could make one, it would be overly unreadable and complex. I suggest you simply have multiple checks; for example:

```
valid = str.length >= 3 && str.length <= 20        # or str.length.between? 3, 20
        && str =~ /^[^-_]+([-_][^-_]{3,})*[-_]?[^-_]+$/
        && str.count '-_' <= 2
        && str.count '0-9' <= 3
        && str.count 'A-Za-z' >= 3
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
/
  [^-_]+      # any amount of non-dashes/underscores (so it can't start with one)
  (
    [-_]      # a dash/underscore
    [^-_]{3,} # 3 or more non-dashes/underscores
  )
  *           # zero or more times
  [-_]?       # an optional dash/underscore
  [^-_]+      # any amount of non-dashes/underscores (so it can't end with one)
/x
```

Comment: +1. Trying to make a kitchen-sink pattern is a slow descent into madness. I much rather prefer seeing several small, easily digestible, patterns, especially when I'm going to have to look at someone else's code.

Comment: Since you use the negative character class `[^-_]` the pattern allows any special characters (`#!^$*%...`). To ensure that there is only dashes, underscores, letters and digits you must change it to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `[^\W_]`. Another thing, why not using `valid = str.length.between?(3, 20)` (not tested)?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Where does it say special characters are not allowed? I suppose I could use `between?`; I'll edit the post

Comment: @Doorknob: You are right, it is said nowhere! I have assumed by the numbers that there isn't special characters by reading the example strings! However it can be a false assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one last question to your regex: Why are you using `[-_]` before `[^-_]` ? Wouldn't I just want that part to allow any character but dash&underscore to be given 3 or more times? Means I'd just leave `[-_]` out. Thanks :)

Comment: @Just If you removed it, though, you wouldn't be able to use dashes or underscores at all!

Comment: I played a bit with your regexp and noticed that if I left it out, I wouldn't be able to use 2 - or _ in the string. only 1 would be allowed. Makes sense, because that part I was asking for in my last comment describes the case when I want to enter a second dash: `abc-abc-`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with `/^(?![-_])[-_a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}(?<![-_])$/`, which will allow all of your ok-usernames and only one of the not-ok (see [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/DRDSCWpINE) for details). Then continue as [Doorknob suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741925/1266906) and impose limits on the frequencies - and _ are used, ...

How - and _ at beginning and end are suppressed?

- `(?![-_])` ensures the next character is neither a - nor _
- `(?<![-_])` ensures the previous character is neither a - nor _